# Viewport render freezing, Task Manager won't quit Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu

Blender randomly freezes when I move the camera in viewport render mode (Cycles). Viewport turns grey and even Task Manager -> End Task cannot close Blender after this happens. To close Blender, I have to restart PC. 
What I noticed is that GPU clock is still high as if the frozen Blender is still rendering.
I reinstalled graphics drivers, but the problem is still there.
Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with your graphics driver. Try to update it and check if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I even tried to roll back to older driver and reinstall the newest one but nothing works.

Comment: So it happens only with two GPUs rendering in viewport simultaneously. One gpu seems to be working fine.